# Android Kernel source/revision/config from kernel build number

Tags: android, kernel

I am working on my hello-android app, which involves using the VpnService class to inspect traffic from specific apps (if anyone knows a better method, please let me know).  Doing so requires the TUN/TAP driver, which is not included in the Verizon Galaxy Nexus, emulated Galaxy Nexus, or Verizon Moto X, and is also not available via the Tun.ko installer app.

The android source appears to be a bit of a fragmented mess, and I'm trying to find a good resource for understanding things.

Specifically:

- Google maintains 8 kernel source repositories and loosely maps some of the devices to those repositories.  Does a more comprehensive mapping exist somewhere?
- None of the real-world android devices/emulators I am currently using have a /proc/config.gz.  Verizon customer support has encountered this issue before, and indicated that the manufacturer produces the image (Verizon sends their bloatware to them for inclusion).  The settings page indicates that the kernel was compiled by a bot within Google proper.  The kernel includes some default configs in arch//configs, but using that requires knowledge of the appropriate git branch and also the appropriate config from within that directory.  There have been some indications that for a galaxy nexus, one should use tuna_defconfig (though that file is not always present for the arm architecture).  Does anyone know of a robust process for determining the correct kernel config to use?
- The kernel version (g9f818de in this case) does not appear anywhere in the git logs for kernel source repository (omap in this case, which is supposed to be used for the galaxy nexus).  Does anyone know how to map kernel build numbers to a source repository/commit?
- Once I find the correct source/version/config, I'll also need to be able to load the module on a non-rooted device.  Attempts with test-modules yield either Function not Implemented, or EACCESS (don't recall the message).
- edit: The build number -> tag mapping indicated in https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html does not appear to apply to the kernel sources (at least not the omap repository)

Any pointers to thorough and accurate documentation would be appreciated.

**Edit - Partial resolution to original problem, but questions remain**

I spoke with the guy who wrote the OpenVPN app, and he was kind enough to point out that:

- Basically all 4.0+ should work out of the box with the VPNService API.
- Also the Android 4.4 emulator is broken.